# What is the correct way to place each option of a ngx-bootstrap-multiselect on it's own row?

Tags: css, angular

I just upgraded an Angular 8 project to Angular 9 and I'm trying out [ngx-bootstrap-multiselect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap-multiselect).

The way the items are placed on one line creates for a wonky display (where sometimes checkbox for subsequent items are displayed to the right of the preceding item).

[image]

Is there a setting that directly controls this?  If not, what's the recommended alternative (I'm thinking  of using itemClasses).

Comment: `.whatewer-selector-for-checkbox-wrapper{display: block;}`?

Comment: @Justinas I tried that initially, but it didn't work.  I had to add `::ng-deep` in order to for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Justinas comment, I was able to get the items to display correctly by adding this to the parent component css file:

```
::ng-deep span[role="menuitem"]{
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

The component still exhibits some strange behavior.  When a single item is clicked, every item is selected:
[image]

I think it is due to the fact that the component requires Bootstrap 4 (I am on Bootstrap 3).  Related thread here: https://github.com/softsimon/ngx-bootstrap-multiselect/issues/462#issuecomment-560370149

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use **itemClasses** or you can easily create your own custom multiselect dropdown.

Comment: The downvote didn't come from me, but this doesn't work for me.